# Error: Could not find or load main class testpkg.simple

Tags: java

I am new to Java and try to running a simple program named "simple" but facing the below error at runtime. I have set the CLASSPATH and PATH variable in the system. .java and .class files are in the same directory and in the cmd prompt, I am running from this directory only. class name and the file name are also same.

Error: Could not find or load main class testpkg.simple

```
package testpkg;
public class simple 
{
public static void main(String args[])
{  
System.out.println("Welcome to package");
} 
}
```

Class file Loc: "D:\testpkg"
Running as: D:\testpkg>java testpkg.simple
Path Var: C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0_67\bin;
C:\Program Files\java\jdk1.7.0_67\jre
Class path: .;D:\testpkg
Windows: xp sp3

It is working if removing "package jav.testpkg;" from the program. it looks like something is wrong with package but unable to point out, gone through many articles and came to this point but still no luck!
Your help appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

run from `D:\` as `java testpkg.simple`

since your class declare package name, your class name is `testpkg.simple` and that class is located relatively at `D:\` so execute it from there

Answer (score 0):

As Jigar already mentioned
your package name is `testpkg` you need to create a folder by the name of testpkg and save the class inside it.

Now suppose your .java file is saved in `D:/testpkg` for compiling the program
open the terminal at `D:/`
then compile it using

```
javac testpkg/simple.java
```

and execute it like this

```
java testpkg.simple
```